# Getting all Datasets and/or Feature classes and consequently spatial data from Esri Structures in MS SQL

Tags: export, sql-server, ogrinfo

I'm looking for query Esri data on MS SQL Server (best by using pure SQL).
So far I'm using ArcPy from Esri Python toolset but that is far from being optimal.

Example of iterating through the entire set (not necessarily exporting the data - that's just for illustration)

```
datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type='feature')
datasets = [''] + datasets if datasets is not None else []

for ds in datasets:
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=ds):
        if  fc == 'OrangeCountyLandRecords.DBO.PinNumbersLatLong':
        print(fc) 
        arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(fc, directory)
```

In addition, I tried ogr2ogr and ogrinfo which in my case does not returning same data as the ArcPy does. Not because of the utilities but rather due to incompatible format, ancient, mismanaged or damaged Esri structures on the server.

Comment: Why the `ogrinfo` tag if you want a "pure SQL" solution?

Comment: I wanted to use the ogrinfo and ogr2ogr at first in same manner as the arcpy, due to issues with the server was unable to. I think the tag can help someone in same scenario - save few days of searching or coding.

Comment: "Ancient structures" is right. Exporting database tables to shapefile is usually a mistake, since shapefile corrupts table names, wide strings, numeric NULLs, datetime,... *and* has a limited file size.

Comment: The reason you can't find documentation on the three-table architecture in SQL Server is that it hasn't been allowed in the past decade. Native geometry has been effective and efficient longer than that. So you're basically making recommendations on the best buggy whip while others are driving hover-cars powered by Mister Fusion.

Answer (score 0):

On MSSQL with the ArcSDE schema you can run

```
select items_a.Name as FeatureClass, items_b.Name as DataSet
from sde.GDB_ITEMS items_a
join sde.GDB_ITEMRELATIONSHIPS rels on rels.DestID = items_a.UUID
join sde.GDB_ITEMS items_b on items_b.UUID = rels.OriginID
join sde.GDB_ITEMTYPES types_a on types_a.UUID = items_a.Type
join sde.GDB_ITEMTYPES types_b on types_b.UUID = items_b.Type
where types_a.Name = 'Feature Class' and types_b.Name = 'Feature Dataset'
order by DataSet, FeatureClass
```

which will list the Datasets and Feature Classes.

Verified the name is seen in ESRI ecosystem -> then find the Feature class ID

Some resources !! wrongly !! (in my case) suggested:

```
SELECT * FROM [OrangeCountyLandRecords].[dbo].[SDE_table_registry]
WHERE table_name = 'PinNumbersLatLong'
```

Correct was:

```
SELECT * FROM [OrangeCountyLandRecords].[dbo].[SDE_layers] 
WHERE table_name = 'PinNumbersLatLong'
```

Field [layer_id] identifies by number some other tables on the server - all related to given Feature class. In this case table named [f20] - other layers/tables are [f#] where # is the layer_id number. ( I was in 2 days unable to find anywhere the "exact" definition just fragmets of needed info about the ESRI tables and fields )

Based on the field and its value I was able get all I need:

```
SELECT P.*, F.* 
FROM [OrangeCountyLandRecords].[dbo].[PinNumbersLatLong] P 
JOIN [OrangeCountyLandRecords].[dbo].[f20] F 
ON P.shape = F.fid
```

Calling the query(s) from any client or code - I get the structures - and/or the data.

Links to ESRI:
[Enterprise geodatabase system tables ArcMap 10.8](http://Enterprise%20geodatabase%20system%20tables)
[Geodatabase system tables in SQL Server ArcMap 10.8](http://Geodatabase%20system%20tables%20in%20SQL%20Server%2010.8)

Base on other users comments:
`select * from sometable_evw` if versioned.

Comment: This is not "all spatial data". It's just metadata.

Comment: I expanded the answer - thank you for pointing that out. I hope now it is all clear and helpful.

Comment: Oh, my. Three table architecture is decades old, and hasn't been supported in a dozen major releases. Are you running this on Pentium NT machines?  This certainly isn't of any use to anyone using modern software.

Comment: I have gov "customers" who still have MS Server 2008 and using ArcView on Win XP. That is exactly why this is important as some of the data I work with never be converted to newer system for foreseeable future - yet I'm trying to implement workaround to streamline and automate. I found old C libraries which can do this but need tedious work. I'm sure I'm not the only one on the planet. Some of the old data exist only as SQL backups as plain SQL dumps.   I got two downvotes for this, yet no answer. If everything deviating from the "ordinary" get down votes we will not resolve anything.